# PHP+SQL Server: Как вывести ошибку?

Tags: php, sql-server

Добрый день.
Подскажите функцию для вывода ошибки (аналог mysql_error) средствами PHP при работе с SQL Server или альтернативный способ узнать ошибку.
P.S. При неудачном коннекте к базе ни какой ошибки не выскакивает. Коннекчусь функцией mssql_connect("хост","логин","пасс")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mssql_get_last_message()`](http://php.net/mssql-get-last-message)

> Returns last error message from server, or an empty string if no error messages are returned from MSSQL.

**UPD.** К сожалению, нету сервера под рукой, что бы проверить, но возможно он генерирует стандартные ошибки PHP. Убедитесь, что у вас включено логирование ошибок:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Или, если ваш код не завязан на mssql расширении, можете воспользоватся [ODBC](http://php.net/mssql-get-last-message) драйвером.

И еще обратите внимание на функции в "See Also" в описании mssql_get_last_message()

Comment: Функцией пользовался: mssql_connect(...) or die(mssql_get_last_message()). Получаю пустую строку при ошибке - ошибка есть, но эта функция её не возвращает.

Comment: Спасибо.
Логирование ошибок не было включено на моём хостинге, включил, ошибки отображаются.
Так же попробовал работать при помощи ODBC драйвера, но коннект с его помощью на денвере долго обрабатывается.
Спасибо ещё раз, хороший ресурс - форумчане отвечают быстро, админ участвует в решении вопроса и в конечном итоге проблему помогают решить.